# Set multiple Child Of constraints properly

Tags: animation, constraints

I didn't see another question/answer on this topic - please point it out if you know of one.

I'm trying to get these two characters to pass this canteen. Making one Child Of constraint, to make the guy on the right pick it up off the table (previous shot) was easy. Getting that constraint to let go, and transfer to the guy on the left, isn't working. When I set right guy's constraint to 0, the canteen floats away. Switching "set inverse" and "clear inverse" doesn't seem to work.

For now, my workaround is to cut the scene at that frame, save the file as the next shot in sequence, and pick up the animation where this one leaves off. That way I can eliminate the constraints on one and have the other immediately start.

Thanks!

https://pasteall.org/blend/edcd0ebaa2844b7c9618db10fa6bdfcc

Comment: It might - I'll try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add-on dynamic parent is very handy for such tasks:

https://github.com/romanvolodin/dynamic_parent

Also, there is a button next to influence value, "disable and keep transform". You can press it and then keyframe location rotation - and then you can use the object for next constraint.